# The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, request

I have a web service file and I am trying to get the URL of the website in order to pass it to the client.  Unfortunately, I am getting the error "The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context".

This is the code:

```
string url = Request.Url.ToString().Substring(0, Request.Url.ToString().LastIndexOf("/")) + "CheckOut.aspx";
```

This is my list of references at the top of the page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Provider.Classes;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;

namespace Server
{
    public class VendorAppService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string StartPayment(string paymentDetails, byte[] signature)
```

Is there a workaround around this?  thank you

**Update**

When I right-click on Request, the Visual Studio IDE does not bring up the Resolve option.

Comment: In what context is the code being executed? Are you able to access `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` perhaps?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is also giving me an error.  This time in the browser: Corrupted Content Error
      
      
      
      
      
        
        
          The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request is not available in WebServices, you can pass it as an argument or set it in a variable in some class and access it here

Comment: No worries, please mark this as an answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: @bazz You'll have to be a little more patient; users cannot accept answers before 15 minutes have passed since asking the question. Let's hope Joe doesn't forget to accept your answer when the time comes ;)